# Time to install Windows 10 from disk

Tags: windows-10, installation

So I want to install Windows 10 (64 bit) from a disk and wanted to know if it needs an internet connection and how much time it will take.

Comment: It will need to down-load around 3GB, so work it out from your internet speed. If you down-load an installation disc, you don't _need_ an internet connection during the installation, though it's useful to install updates while installing, and you need the internet for this, of course.

Comment: It will offer to update the install for you, that's an optional step, and it clearly indicates that step is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft support says it will take an hour to do a clean [install of Windows 10](https://www.quora.com/How-long-does-it-take-to-install-Windows-10) but that link quotes 20 minutes for the 64-bit version on an SSD and about 30 minutes on a mechanical HD.  I would lean toward the 1 hour estimate to be careful.

You [do not need](http://www.tomshardware.com/faq/id-2569562/install-windows.html) an internet connection for the installation if you have the full 3-4 GB ISO file saved and burned to a disk.  An internet connection is only required to connect to your Microsoft account.

Always make sure you have any data you want to save backed up when installing an OS.

Comment: The installation itself really does not take too long but the updates afterwards will take on more time. Get your hand on any ISO younger than Release 1511. Otherwise Updates will take even longer.

Comment: Those times are for a clean install.  It will take longer if you choose to keep your files, programs, and settings, how long it takes, depends on several factors.  Simply said, don't plan to use your computer, and then start the upgrade.

Comment: @Ramhound Good point, I just assumed it was going to be a clean install.